# context Api não mostra valor no consumer

Tags: javascript, react

Eu comecei a estudar agora context api, acredito que estou fazendo o meu codigo com a mesma estrutura dos tutoriais, porém o component de destino do valor não recebe nada, fica apenas um espaço em branco onde devia ter ele.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const CarContext = React.createContext();

function context(){
  return(
    <CarContext.Provider value='car'>
    </CarContext.Provider>
  );
}

function App(){
  return(
    <CarContext.Consumer>
      {value => (
        <p>a{value}</p>
      )}
    </CarContext.Consumer>
  )
}

export default App;
```

O que está faltando para o código funcionar?

Comment: `CarContext.Provider` e `CarContext.Consumer` o que seria esses dois componentes?

Comment: são o provider e o consumer da context, que são os componentes de envio e recebimento dos dados globais

Comment: Você ta vendo esse componentes como? porque o `Consumer` realmente não faz nada!

Comment: o consumer mostra o que tem dentro dele, eu arrumei, na verdade tinha esquecido de chamar a função context antes dele, chamando ela funcionou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se entendi bem o que você queria fazer, mas como você deve ter estudado, o `Context.Provider` repassa os dados para os componentes filhos através do `Context.Consumer`. Na minha visão, o `Provider`deveria estar no nó mais alto da árvore componente, que no caso seria o `App`, e no seu código está trocado. Fiz um exemplo de código para ajudá-lo.

```js
const CarContext = React.createContext();

class CarComponent extends React.Component {
 render() {
   return (
  <CarContext.Consumer>
    {value => <p>My Car: {value}</p>}
  </CarContext.Consumer>
   );
 }
}

class App extends React.Component {
 render() {
   const value = "BMW";
   return (
  <CarContext.Provider value={value}>
    <CarComponent />
  </CarContext.Provider>
   );
 }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Espero ter ajudado! '-'

Comment: Na verdade eu deixei como a camada mais alta o context mesmo
o que eu tinha feito de errado foi não ter chamado o context antes de chamar o consumer, mas obrigado pela ajuda, a sua versão tambem funcionaria, mas é que eu quero deixar o context na camada mais alta mesmo :D

Comment: Belo exemplo Julia, o nosso site tem um forma de colocar o código rodando como demostrando em minha edição para contribuir com a sua resposta.

Comment: Obrigada, @VirgilioNovic.